# can not access mongod

Tags: mongodb, apple-m1

I have installed and reinstalled homebrewthen,
I have installed mongodb-community@5.0 However, when I type
`mongod --dbpath ./mongo-db-data/` 
in the terminal, I get
`zsh: command not found: mongod`
please help

I am working on a mac M1

Comment: Usually `mongod` is installed in `/usr/bin/mongod` which is included in `PATH`. Are you sure, the installation was successful? Did you create folder `mongo-db-data`?

Comment: Also check your `.bashrc` file. If it has an export statement for mongo, then add it to your `.zshrc` too (or just go head and add this to your `.zshrc`) --> `export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH`